# Changement de thème graphique pour notre site

Tags: discussion, user-interface, design

L'apparence et l'interface de notre site viennent de changer. Il s'agit d'une vague de changements qui concerne tous les sites du [réseau Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

Quelques sites avaient déjà la nouvelle apparence, notamment [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) qui a été [le premier site de test](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16736/new-stock-theme-roll-out) pour les sites qui n'ont pas de thème en propre.

Les [principales nouveautés](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310908/live-left-nav-new-theming-and-responsiveness) sont :

- Une nouvelle barre apparaît à gauche. Certains des boutons qui apparaissent actuellement en haut de page (liens “Questions”, “Tags”, “Users”, “Unanswered”) sont désormais dans la barre de gauche. Pour les gens qui ont une fenêtre très large, l'espace à gauche sera ainsi un peu mieux utilisé. Pour ceux qui ont une fenêtre plus étroite, la barre de gauche peut être désactivée en cochant la case « Hide left navigation » sur [votre page de préférences utilisateur](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current). Lorsque la barre est désactivée, on peut faire apparaître les boutons qu'elle contient en cliquant sur le bouton `≡` en haut à gauche.
- Le nouveau thème est partiellement [adaptatif](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site_web_adaptatif) à la largeur de fenêtre. Toutes les pages n'ont pas encore été adaptées, donc le site restera encore difficile à utiliser avec une fenêtre étroite pendant un moment. De plus, la largeur du bandeau publicitaire à droite est fixe, donc de bandeau peut occuper une grande partie de l'espace dans une fenêtre de largeur intermédiaire. Si cela vous gêne, la seule solution possible actuellement sans script ou extension est de rendre la fenêtre plus étroite : le bandeau de gauche est alors relégué en bas de page.
- [Les liens hypertextes sont maintenant soulignés](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314275/underline-appearing-for-hyperlinks). On aime ou on n'aime pas…

Le thème « mobile » n'est pas concerné par ce changement.

Si vous avez des remarques sur ce changement et que vous parlez anglais, je vous invite à en faire part sur le site méta principal via les liens ci-dessus, notamment [le fil sur la conception adaptative et la barre de gauche](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315662/responsive-design-coming-to-all-beta-undesigned-sites-soon) et [l'annonce du déploiement du nouveau thème sur les sites bêtas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315662/responsive-design-coming-to-all-beta-undesigned-sites-soon). Si vous préférez le français, vous pouvez faire vos remarques ou poser des questions sous forme de réponse ici-même.

Answer (score 1):

Je trouve personnellement trop grande la taille de cette catégorie d'éléments (*All Questions* etc.) :

[image]

*Élément « All Questions »*

[image]

*Police du titre d'une question (« Changement de thème... »)*

Est-ce en fait la même police que pour le titre d'une question ? J'ai parcouru des contenus ([1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319274), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315762/342658)) mais honnêtement c'est un peu compliqué. J'aimerais connaître le nom de la catégorie d'éléments en question pour pouvoir m'exprimer sur le sujet. Pourrait-on svp. me confirmer si c'est bien un élément qui s'applique au réseau en entier ou si un site particulier peut le modifier ?

Comment: Tous les sites « Beta » ont la même charte graphique. Et même les sites qui ont leur propre charte graphique n'ont pas beaucoup de variations, je crois qu'ils ont les mêmes tailles de police. Je ne sais pas ce que tu cherches comme « nom de la catégorie ».

Comment: @Gilles Merci pour l'info. ! Je pensais qu'il y avait un nom dans l'abstrait pour cet élément-là, mais je pense sans doute à un truc comme _top header_, l'_entête en haut à gauche du masque de contenu du centre_ ou un truc comme ça, finalement je suis peut-être mieux de garder l'image... Oui je crois qu'on trouve l'effet « All Questions » sur tous les sites, qu'ils soient en « beta » ou non. En fait j'aimerais que la police ne soit pas plus grande que celle de « French language », par exemple. Ça reste un détail...

Comment: Incidemment, sais-tu si le champ d'un commentaire a été modifié avec la refonte ? Plus particulièrement sais-tu si le comportement suivant a toujours eu lieu : dans un commentaire de 8 lignes, en utilisant la roulette de la souris, je ne suis pas capable de voir complètement la ligne 4, à moins d'utiliser les flèches du clavier pour atteindre la ligne avec plus de précision. Je sais pas si c'est clair. J'ai l'impression que le _viewport_ du champ n'affichait pas de demi-ligne auparavant, mais souvent quand il y a des changements les utilisateurs y voient la cause de trucs préexistants. Merci !

Comment: Si je comprends bien le CSS, « French Language Beta » et « All Questions » ont la même taille (2.07692308 [rem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography)#CSS)), et sont en plus gras. Pour le commentaire, je ne vois pas un tel effet. Le comportement de roulette dépend du navigateur et du système d'exploitation.

Comment: @Gilles Merci pour ces précisions ! Le « All Questions » m'a l'air plus grand mais c'est sans doute uniquement une impression. Il n'est pas assez différemment plus petit que French Language à mon goût, mais c'est un détail à ce stade-ci. Pour la roulette j'aurais du m'en douter. Une autre raison d'être sur Linux. Merci encore !